# prevent ios simulator from asking "x Would like to use your current location"

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-simulator, core-location

We are running a test automation suite and would like to prevent this message from appearing when using the iOS Simulator. Can anyone come up with a hack to automatically enable this when deploying a new app to the simulator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do not put the

```
 if([CLLocationMannager isLocationServicesEnabled])
```

check before u start the `CLLocationManager`.
This boolean implicitly calls the Alert before the App starts finding the user location.

Also, the macros-

```
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR

  code..without the if([CLLocationMannager isLocationServicesEnabled]) condition
//Simulator

#else
if([CLLocationMannager isLocationServicesEnabled]){code..}
// Device
#endif
```

can be put to use here..

Answer (score 1):

In your Console there will be an option Don't simulate Location, watch the screen shot , you will get an idea
[image]